# Is it possible to force a TeamCity build to rebuild dependencies when triggered over HTTP?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.1

Based on the TeamCity documentation I can see that it is possible to trigger a build over http:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP

For example,

```
http://testuser:testpassword@teamcity.jetbrains.com/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=bt10
```

However, I need to force a build to also rebuild certain dependencies when it is added to the queue. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force TeamCity to rebuild all dependencies if you add rebuildDependencies=true to query string:

```
http://testuser:testpassword@teamcity.jetbrains.com/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=bt10&rebuildDependencies=true
```

It is also possible to rebuild dependencies partially, but it is not easy as you'd need to retrieve some internal ids somehow but these ids aren't usually shown anywhere on the page.