# Can I configure TeamCity to NOT start build chain before it is completed?

Tags: teamcity, continuous-deployment

*(Similar to: [Is it possible to prevent a build chain from being interrupted in TeamCity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623473/is-it-possible-to-prevent-a-build-chain-from-being-interrupted-in-teamcity))*

I have the following build chain:

1. Proj A - Build and Install Environment
2. Proj B,C,D - Test Environment

So Proj A runs, then Projs B,C & D.

The problem is A may start before B, C or D finishes, resulting in the environment being rebuilt while tests are run against it.

Is there a way to tell TeamCity to complete the **entire chain** before it starts a new chain?

Things I've thought of:

1. I don't want to limit to a build agent so that B, C & D are run in
   parallel and quickly
2. I could add a delay for Proj A's VC trigger, but that's a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of TeamCity are you using? If using version 8.0 or higher, you could define a [Shared Resource](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/05/explaining-the-shared-resources-plugin/) in projects B, C and D (they would be defined as using the resource in read mode), and define project A as using that resource in write mode with a resource quota of 1. That should prevent project A of running while any of the others are running.

Comment: I have 7.1. Will upgrade and try out. Thanks.